# Can we use variables inside '''?

Tags: python

Can we use variables inside ''' in python?

Example

```
friend = str('Jake')

pnt = '''
hello {friend}
'''
print(pnt)
```

Something like this ?

Comment: Use [Formatted String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

Comment: Have you tried putting an `f` in front of the three quotes? And `'Jake'` is a string literal, there is no point in casting a string to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Yeh i got a solution . Thanks to [Grismar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4390160/grismar)  & [Abdul Niyas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699447/abdul-niyas-p-m)

```
friend = str('Jake')

pnt = f'''
hello {friend}
'''
print(pnt)
```

Yes .. just put f in front of `'''` . I read about it and i understood that it is called Formatted string literals

Answer (score 0):

You can use Formatted string literals:

```
friend = str('Jake')

pnt = f'''
hello {friend}
'''
print(pnt)
>> hello Jake
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals

Also, you can use the .format method:

```
friend = str('Jake')

pnt = '''
hello {}
'''.format(friend)
print(pnt) 
>> hello Jake
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format